# I want to know what is the point of using pointer in first code when we can get same result using second code

Tags: c++, pointers

## First code file that contains pointer `*ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int size;
    int *ptr;

    std::cout << "Enter number of values you want to store (size of array): ";
    std::cin >> size;

    ptr = new int[size];
    std::cout << "Enter values to be stored in the array: " << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        std::cin >> ptr[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Values in the array are: " << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        i == 0 ? std::cout << ptr[i] : std::cout << " " << ptr[i] ;
    }

    delete[] ptr; //Freeing the dynamically allocated memeory(in order to avoid memory leak)
    return 0;
}
```

## Second code file which doesn't contain any pointer but still giving same result:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int size;

    std::cout << "Enter number of values you want to store(size of the array): ";
    std::cin >> size;
    int theArray[size];

    std::cout << "Enter values to be stored in the array: " << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        std::cin >> theArray[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Values in the array are : " << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        i == 0 ? std::cout << theArray[i] : std::cout << " " << theArray[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to know why everyone is suggesting me to use first code instead of second.

Please explain it to me.

Comment: `int theArray[size];` uses a C-style Variable Length Array. That's not allowed in Standard C++. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/jo96evnzh

Comment: People suggesting the first code are fools. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for all (well, almost all) your variable length array needs.

Comment: the second file won't compile on windows with the microsoft compiler.

Comment: The people suggesting solution one should read the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).  In current C++ the use of new/delete and "naked pointers" is not recommended.

Comment: The lesson for the second option, always compile with ALL warnings enabled and ignore none of them. As shown here for gcc : https://godbolt.org/z/Tf8jjMrM5. `<source>:8:9: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'theArray' [-Wvla]
    8 |     int theArray[size];`